# Get data from Select box

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a select box in html and Ajax which calls a php page that returns the values of the selected option.

The problem is that when I want to send data to another php page the selection that I got from the ajax call does not get sent.

Index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Booking - Online Belt</title>
</head>
<body>

<center><h3>Book Your Private Transfer</h3>


<form action="./elabora.php" method="POST" id="formregservizio">
<p>DATA
<input type="date" name="data"/>

HOURS <select name="ore">
    <option value="00" selected>00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="vuoto"></option>
</select>

Minuti:<select name="minuti">
    <option value="00" selected>00</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
</select>

Passeggeri:<select name="pax">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

Large Bag<select name="large_bag">
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

Small Bag<select name="small_bag">
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select></p>


<!-- SEZIONE FROM -->
<p>FROM <select name="FROM" id="from">
        <option value="vuoto">Select...</option>
        <?php
        include('./includedb.php');
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT areak FROM weblocalita ORDER BY ordinamento ASC");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['areak'].'">'.$row['areak'].'</option>'; 
            }
    ?>
        </select>

<!-- SEZIONE sub_FROM -->
 <select name ="subfrom" id="subfrom">
        <option value="vuoto">Select...</option>
    </select>
</p>
<!--  SEZIONE TO -->
<p>FROM   
        <select name="to" id="to">
            <option value="vuoto">Select...</option>
        <?php

        include('./includedb.php');
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT areak FROM weblocalita ORDER BY ordinamento ASC");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['areak'].'">'.$row['areak'].'</option>'; 
            }   
    ?>
        </select>

<!-- SEZIONE sub_TO -->
 <select name="subto" id="subto">
    <option value="vuoto">Select...</option>
    </select>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"   integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from').on('change',function(){
        var scelta = $(this).val();
        if(scelta){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'./update_status.php',
                data:'scelta='+scelta,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#subfrom').html(html); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#subfrom').html("<option>Errore</option>");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#to').on('change',function(){
        var sceltadestinazione = $(this).val();
        var sceltadopo = $('#subfrom').val();
        if(sceltadestinazione){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'./update_status.php',
                data:'sceltadestinazione='+sceltadestinazione,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#subTO').html(html); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#subto').html("<option>Errore</option>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the PHP page that is called by the Ajax Request:

update_status.php

```
<?php

    include('./includedb.php');
    $area = $_POST['scelta'];
    if($area == 'vuoto') {
        echo '<option value="'."vuoto".'">'."Select...".'</option>';
    }
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT klocalita FROM weblocalita WHERE areak = '$area'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['klocalita'].'">'.$row['klocalita'].'</option>';
        }

    $areadestinazione = $_POST['sceltadestinazione'];
    $sceltadopo = $_POST['sceltadopo'];

    if($areadestinazione == 'vuoto') {
        echo '<option value="'."vuoto".'">'."Select...".'</option>';
    }

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT klocalita FROM weblocalita WHERE areak = '$areadestinazione'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['klocalita'].'">'.$row['klocalita'].'</option>';
        }


?>
```

And now from Index.php I want to send the data to another page in php called Elabora.php that should display all data sent.

Elabora.php

```
    <center>
        <h3>Configure Service</h3>

        Dati Inseriti:<br>
        Date: <?php echo $_POST['data']; ?>
        Hours: <?php echo $_POST['ore']; ?>
        Minutes: <?php echo $_POST['minuti']; ?>
        Px: <?php echo $_POST['pax']; ?>
        Large Bags: <?php echo $_POST['large_bag']; ?>
        Small Bags: <?php echo $_POST['small_bag']; ?><br>
        From: <?php echo $_POST['from'] . $_POST['subfrom'];?><br>
        To: <?php echo $_POST['to'] . $_POST['subto'];?><br>
</center>
```

Now the problem is that the select boxes with the IDs: From and To are not sent to the elabora.php page.

Comment: That's a lot of code ... but as far as I oversee ... your jQuery functions sends just a single parameter-value-pair.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Select need a name-attribute, if you want to get it through POST.

```
<select id="subTO">
<option value="vuoto">Select...</option>
</select>
```

should be:

```
<select id="subTO" name="subTo">
<option value="vuoto">Select...</option>
</select>
```

I also noticed:

```
<select name=TO id=to>
```

You're missing the "" here.

Comment: I added them but it doesn't change anything

Comment: You can do a var_dump($_POST); to see what's coming through
By the way, check your spelling. "subTo" is not the same as "subto".
If you're select has name="subTo" you have to get $_POST["subTo"];

Comment: It seems like it's getting them, this is the result of var_dump: array(9) { ["data"]=> string(10) "2018-03-07" ["ore"]=> string(2) "03" ["minuti"]=> string(2) "20" ["pax"]=> string(1) "1" ["large_bag"]=> string(1) "0" ["small_bag"]=> string(1) "0" ["FROM"]=> string(15) "Venice Terminal" ["TO"]=> string(12) "Venice Hotel" ["submit"]=> string(4) "NEXT" }